# SQL Server partition unnormalized data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, normalization, database-partitioning

I think there might be a way to partition this to find what I want, but I can't see it. I have some slightly *unnormalized* data about product sets:

```
SetItemID   ComponentItemID quantity    IsPrimary
123         234             1           1
123         345             2           0
456         567             3           1
456         678             2           0
```

I need to find sets where the `quantity`'s described are, for example, `IsPrimary` component's `quantity` > 'IsPrimary=0`component's`quantity. I also need to find sets where quantities are equal between components, etc. **It's ok to use multiple statements for this, if necessary**

All I have so far is a partial `PARTITION` statement that may or may not be the right way to do this, but I can't figure out *how to compare quantities within sets*:

```
WITH setdata as
(select *, row_number() OVER(
    PARTITION by s.setitemid order by s.setitemid) position from set_table s )
// descending just to get newer sets
SELECT* from setdata order by setitemid desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following your requirements right, this should do it:

```
SELECT p1.SetItemId
 from (--  IsPrimary = 1
       select SetItemID, ComponentItemId, Quantity
        from SetData
        where IsPrimary = 1) p1
  inner join (--  IsPrimary = 0
              select SetItemID, ComponentItemId, Quantity
               from SetData
               where IsPrimary = 0) p0
   on p0.SetItemID = p1.SetItemID
    and p1.Quantity > p0.Quantity
  --and p1.Quantity = p0.Quantity
```

Use that last line for sets with equal quantities.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   set_table a
WHERE  isPrimary = 1
       AND quantity > (SELECT quantity
                       FROM   set_table b
                       WHERE  a.setItemId = b.setItemId
                              AND isPrimary = 0)
ORDER  BY setItemId DESC
```

Or

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   set_table a
       INNER JOIN set_table b
               ON a.setItemId = b.setItemId
                  AND a.isPrimary = 1
                  AND b.isPrimary = 0
WHERE  a.quantity > b.quantity
```